# How to create a blank ModernWindow using ModernUI?

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

I have followed the MUI guide provided here: http://mui.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20your%20own%20navigation%20framework
but that doesn't work because the BlankWindow resource is not available.

Then someone aswked about it here: http://mui.codeplex.com/workitem/19663
and the developer replied that the user should recompile the library using the latest source code.

I've downloaded the latest source code from here: http://mui.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest
but upon compilation, the resulting library is the same that's distributed online.

So at the moment I am confused in regard to solving this issue. Could anyone provide some support please?

Comment: if you want, cou can take a look in to http://mahapps.com/ it's another great modern ui styling lib...

Comment: I know of alternative solutions, but I am interested in ModernUI.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Resharper?
Look [here](https://mui.codeplex.com/discussions/441270), this is maybe only designer problem.
I have the same issue... But I can normaly build and run my application.
They say:

> Weird. I am having the same issue on my machine (VS2012 + Resharper).
> It works fine when I run it but it's failing to build in TeamCity. Ill
> keep investigating...
>
> I am running a program created via the MUI template in VS. Try to
> remove it from resharper error/warning.  Resharper can force a simple
> warning to an error if a wrong setting is set.

Comment: Please put the context of the link in your answer, so that in case the link goes down, your remains relevant.